# My Conditional0 JSON statement is not working as expected

Tags: json, sharepoint

I have two fields that I am interogating.

1. [$WF_x0020_Status]
2. [$WorkflowRequired]

The button should only show up when the WF Status = 'Not Started' or if the WorkFlowRequired field is not set or not equal to 'None'.  My code is not working as expected. What am I doing incorrectly?

Here is my JSON

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "button",
  "txtContent": "Launch flow",
  "customRowAction": {
    "action": "executeFlow",
    "actionParams": "{\"id\": \"b9ac6fa1-f0ee-4299-a5e1-cc84ec667b80\"}"
  },
  "style": {
    "background-color": "#3366ff",
    "color": "white",
    "visibility": "=if([$WF_x0020_Status] == 'Not Started' && [$WorkflowRequired]<>'None'),'visible','hidden')"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the below：

```
"visibility": "=if(([$WF_x0020_Status] == 'Not Started'  && [$WorkflowRequired]!='None' ),'visible','hidden')"
```

Comment: Worked like a charm!
Interesting that you used "!" important
Can you please explain why your changes worked?
Thank you!

Comment: Operator "!=" means not qual to. SharePoint donot use "<>"

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you!